# Android App v0.1.4 fails to load feed

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Got the update for 0.1.4 and I can't get the feed to load on WiFi or 3G. I just get the toast saying failed to load data. Other parts of the app are functioning correctly. The feed worked minutes before I updated the app as well.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: interesting. works here on my nexus 4 on 4.3...

Comment: @jrg Nexus 4 on 4.3 as well. Still happening after a restart too.

Comment: @StevenV Any chance you can send over a logcat over? Either upload here or e-mail to krahjerdi@stackexchange.com you can use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) to get the log file off your phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an event in your reputation history that we weren't explicitly checking.  This should be fixed and your feed should load.

Comment: Looks good! Props on the responsiveness!

Comment: I'm getting the same error on version 0.1.56

Comment: @BenitoBertoli different error, bad set of changes rolled out earlier.  This should be fixed now, can you try again?

Comment: It's working now.