# Opening Careers notification crashes app

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox, android-app

I got a notification from Careers 2.0 today. Clicking on the notification opened the app, and was promptly followed by a crash.

Now, I know that Careers is probably not a priority for the app, (is it?) so, either notifications from careers should not be shown in the app inbox, or they should directly open up the browser.

Version: 0.1.26

**UPDATE:** It *seems* to have been resolved in 0.1.27 as the notification now opens up in a browser window.

Comment: I know they are checking something with notification/rep types. [My feed completely stopped loading](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192190/215013) after I got rep from a tag wiki edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in version 0.1.27, as you noticed :) Thanks!

Comment: Version .27 is highly unstable. Its crashing almost randomly and very frequently. I am getting a crash every 2-3 minutes. It seems to happen whenever the app is loading anything at all and the connection is lost for a few seconds (not sure about this though).