# Notification panel doesnt like Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, notifications, android-app

Ever since I have received a [notification from Careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196311/200868), clicking on the notifications icon* from within the app crashes it.

I cannot open the notifications panel *at all* now.

Version: 0.1.26

**UPDATE**: It *seems* to have been resolved in 0.1.27 as the notification panel is opening now.

<sub>*Since there seems to be some confusion, I meant clicking on the **notifications icon** and not the *specific careers notification* as mentioned in the previous question.</sub>

Comment: Sounds like some lethal notifications poison!

Comment: Why duplicate the question?

Comment: @nhahtdh Its not the same issue. Added clarification.

Comment: @nhahtdh looks like this is escalation of the previous report, not sure it should be separate report though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause for this and the related crash were both fixed in 0.1.27, thanks!