# Careers ads break the Android app

Tags: bug, jobs, android-app, android-app-feed

Clicking any Careers (or Jobs) ad in the Android app feed results in an instant crash for the Android App version 1.0.89.

Comment: Android version is 5.0.1, I daresay it doesn't matter :/

Comment: I would say this is related to [“Open in browser” crashes when Android app is set as default](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273486/open-in-browser-crashes-when-android-app-is-set-as-default), though I haven't tried to reproduce it.

Comment: Return of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196311/opening-careers-notification-crashes-app), too bad the android app is no longer supported, nobody is working on it. I just wonder when they will announce its End of Life.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Do you have a link?

Comment: @OddDev you mean for the "app is no longer supported" claim? No need for a link.Take a look in the [recent android app bugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app+bug?sort=active&pageSize=50). In those 50 bugs, only two are fixed. One was API bug not related to the app, and one was fixed back in March by the iOS app developer. If the app is still supported and maintained it's just a sad and very bad joke. (on our behalf, they don't even bother to say "OK, we'll fix it at some point", they just ignore all the bugs and requests as if they don't exist)