# Error loading feed

Tags: bug, android-app

Similarly to [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192190/android-app-v0-1-4-fails-to-load-feed)
The app keeps failing to load the feed and I have been receiving this message:

> [image: Feed loading error message]

This isn't limited to this device, it started happening a lot of time ago on my Nexus 5 device. I don't remember exactly when but probably after I requested deletion of some unused stack exchange site accounts.

As the aforementioned issue suggests since this issue transferred devices it probably has to be account related.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: OnePlus
- Device Model: ONEPLUS A5010

  - OS Version: 8.1.0 (3)

**Update:** Apparently I have "Server fault" as one of my stack exchange communities when clicking "show all" on mobile profile page, however, the account has been deleted already and only a blank page is shown. I think this may be the source of the issue.

> [image: Server fault page]